# Anchor tags with same class not returning value on button click in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sorting

I have the following HTML:

```
<a class="sortorder" data-order="asc" >sort ascending</a> 
<a class="sortorder" data-order="desc">sort descending</a>
```

These anchor tags are used to sort values that are returned from mysql table using ajax.

```
$(document).on('click', '.sortorder', function() {
  var order = $(this).attr('data-order');
  //further processing
});
```

The above code returns value `asc` or `desc` depending upon what is clicked. There is also a button which is used to load more data from the mySQL table using AJAX:

```
<button id="loadmore">Load more</button>
```

The jQuery for this button is external to the above jQuery. What I want is that when the `#loadmore` button is clicked it should return the `data-order` value of anchor tags with the `sortorder` class for further processing by AJAX.

For example

```
$("#loadmore").click(function () {
  var order= $('.sortorder').attr('data-order');
  alert(order); // the problem is that this is alerting only asc value
});
```

The issue here is that it is returning only the first value when clicking on the `#loadmore` button. That is in this case it is returning only the `asc` value irrespective of whether data is being sorted out as `asc` or `desc`.

What I what is that when data-order desc is chosen and the loadmore button is clicked, it should return desc and not asc which it is now doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take one hidden input field,

like,

```
<input type="hidden" id="current_order" value="">
```

And then whenever you will click on sortorder class

```
$(document).on('click', '.sortorder', function() {
  var order= $(this).attr('data-order');
  $("#current_order").val(order);
});
```

And then in loadmore,

```
$("#loadmore").click(function () {
  var cur_order =   $("#current_order").val();
 console.log(order);
});
```

You can do this way.

If you want, you can also set, default sorting order value to hidden input field.

Comment: your answer has helped me with the issue. Can you please tell me how can we do similar thing with multiple checkboxes having same class name?

Comment: Checkboxes ? instead of data-order ? I means, if checked desc and if not desc like this ?

Comment: no, multiple checkbox select as an array of value to query for those values in the database. How do I pass an array to hidden field in that case?

Comment: This is out of question thing right ? You want to pass all checked values of checkbox to hidden field ? in that case, convert array by JSON.stringify(your_arr) and save in hidden variable.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because there are multiple `.sortorder` elements. Calling `attr()` on a collection will only return the value of the first element within that collection. To solve this you can use a loop:

```
$("#loadmore").click(function () {
    $('.sortorder').each(function() {
        var order = $(this).data('order');
        console.log(order);

        // further processing
    });
});
```

> What I what is that when data-order desc is chosen and loadmore button is clicked, it should return desc and not asc which it is not doing.

To achieve this you need a method of knowing which button is active. To do this you can place a class on the button when it's clicked and then select the element by that class when `#loadmore` is clicked. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.sortorder', function() {
    $('.sortorder.active').removeClass('active');
    var order = $(this).data('order').addClass('active');

    // further processing
});  

$("#loadmore").click(function () {
    var order = $('.sortorder.active').data('order');
    console.log(order);

    // further processing
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not read order value on button click. Just make the order variable a global one. Try below:

```
var order = "asc";//Global Variable


 $(document).on('click', '.sortorder', function() {
        order = $(this).attr('data-order');
        $("#current_order").val(order);
      });

$("#loadmore").click(function () {
    $('.sortorder').each(function() {
        //var order = $(this).data('order'); //Need not read it again
        console.log(order);
    });
});
```